# Wrong arguments being passed when sourcing script using command substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have a script print.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo printing provided args:

for i in "$@"; do
        echo -e "\t${i}"
done
```

If I do this at the prompt `a=$(. print.sh  ); echo "${a}"`
then I get `printing provided args:` as the stored output

My main script to test command substitution looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function func_to_call_sub_scrp
        {
        # Call  sub-script
        capture="$(. $1  $2 $3)"
        echo -e "captured output:
\t\t${capture}"
        }

echo "Run function to call sub script without parameters passed. "
func_to_call_sub_scrp   print.sh
echo ""
echo "Run function to call sub script with parameters passed."
func_to_call_sub_scrp   print.sh     xx  yy
```

This outputs:

```
Run function to call sub script without parameters passed. 
captured output:
                printing provided args:
        print.sh

Run function to call sub script with parameters passed.
captured output:
                printing provided args:
        xx
        yy
```

The second call sends xx and yy to print.sh which is as expected. However when I send "print.sh" "" "" command substitution calls print.sh and sends it print.sh as its $1 instead of sending it "" and ""

My question is how is $1 being passed as an argument to the printing script when there are no other inputs? I expected `"$(. $1  $2 $3)"` to become `"$(. print.sh   )"` or `"printing provided args:"` once returned.

Comment: What line in the output did you not expect?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're explicitly passing arguments "xx" and "yy" to the function, that's how $2 and $3 are populated. Then when you call "source" (`.`), you're providing them again. At a bash prompt, type `help .`

Comment: @choroba I am confused that calling func_to_call_sub_scrp   print.sh  sends the text 'print.sh' as $1 to print.sh.   the example with 2 arguments shows that it is not passed when actual arguments are supplied.   I will edit the end to make it clear which function call is confusing

Comment: See also: [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you do *not* run `. "print.sh" "" ""` in the first example.  You are running `. print.sh` since you are not quoting `$2` or `$3`.

From the `bash` manual, regarding `source` (and `.`), with my emphasis:

> [...] If any arguments are supplied, they become the
> positional parameters when filename is executed.  *Otherwise the
> positional parameters are unchanged.*

When you call `. print.sh`, you do not provide arguments to the dot-script `print.sh`, and the positional parameters are therefore unchanged.  But what are they?

The positional parameters in the dot-script will in the first call be the positional parameters of your function, which is the list consisting of the single string `print.sh`.  This is why `"$@"` expands to `print.sh` inside the dot-script.

---

Just comments:

A better way to output all positional parameters with a tab indent:

```bsh
printf '\t%s\n' "$@"
```

This avoids issues with `echo` described [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803).  A similar comment could be made about the way you output `$capture` in the function.

You also need to quote the expansion of `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`, unless you want the shell to split them on the characters in `$IFS` and apply filename globbing on the resulting words. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694).